# Change font color of the label and UIImageview image across entire views of the application iOS

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, themes, uilabel

I'm trying to change the theme of the application(UILabel font color and images of UIImageview) based on the condition.

I'm checking one condition, if it is 0 entire label in the application should be in red color else it should be in blue color as well as UIImageview images.

2 sets of images are there. based on the condition i need to change the images also.

Anyone give me some ideas to start..

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You could add a category for `UILabel` which should have the method

```
-(UIColor *)labelColor {

  //depend on ur condition, return the color
}
```

In all the label declarations, set the font color as

```
lbl.textColor = [lbl labelColor];
```

Similarly for `UIImageView`.

**Update:**

Create a new file of type Cocoa-Touch Objective C category through Xcode.

You can name the file like `UILabel+Color` and the interface will be like

```
@interface UILabel (Color)
-(UIColor *)labelColor;
@end
```

In .m file, implement the method as stated at the top.

For more info on Categories, see this [tutorial](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) and [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2)

Comment: Thank u so much for your quick reply :) please explain me little brief

Answer (score 1):

In all your viewcontroller's `viewWillAppear` method, iterate through the subviews and if view is of type `UILabel` then change textcolor. Similarly for `UIImageView`

```
for (UIView *child in view.subviews)
{
    if([child isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)child;
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

I haven't tried, but think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is, create a singleton class, where you will make/change properties of labels/images/buttons, any UI object.

You'll just have to access this class's methods for every UI object, and its done. No need to write multiple lines of code again and again.
:)

Comment: this is brief. did u mean detailed?